# Can I give this Django form an author?

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django here and I need help getting this "form" to get the user id of the currently logged in user.

Here's my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from models import Entry


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'thumbnail')
```

I can't find any documentation on this kind of form implementation, specifically how the "fields" variable works.

I can somewhat get this working by adding author like this:

```
  fields = ('title', 'body', 'thumbnail', 'author')
```

This is almost all I need except this will only add a dropdown list of every registered User.

How can I do something like this in Django?

```
from django import forms
from models import Entry
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'thumbnail')
            fields.author = request.user.username # <-- SEEMS TO NOT DO ANYTHING
```

Or instead of that, how could I code this into the views.py?

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.author = request.user.id # <-- SEEMS TO NOT DO ANYTHING
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/weblog')

    else:
        form = EntryForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form 

    return render_to_response('coltrane/newpost.html', args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the author on the instance, which is the result of form.save(), not on the form.

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.author = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Note that your first attempt would have given a NameError exception (because `request` is not defined in that scope).

Comment: Excellent that worked perfectly! The bottom 3 lines of code is going to be extremely helpful since it's very reusable for any other type of form. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use request.user inside your view instead of request.user.username or request.user.id

```
        form.author = request.user
```